# Cannot create new post by hugo from command line

Tags: command-line, error-handling, themes, hugo

I am using the [Hugo KeepIt](https://github.com/Fastbyte01/KeepIt) theme. The configuration is correct as far as I understand.
However, running the command
`hugo new projects/projectsample.md` gives the following error:
`Error: yaml: line 1: did not find expected key`
I have to create every single file with the front-matter manually.
Can anyone tell me the possible causes and solutions?

Answer (score 1):

By design, your archetype files will override your theme's archetype files if they have the same name. So it's likely that your file:

```
archetypes/default.md
```

Is overriding your theme's file at:

```
themes/KeepIt/archetypes/default.md
```

To fix this, you can do one of the following:

- delete your `archetypes/default.md` file; or
- copy the contents of `themes/KeepIt/archetypes/default.md` and paste them into your `archetypes/default.md` file